# What to use instead of NSEntityDescription in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I am really new to iOS Development. I want to use the Core Data functionality in my application to store the data in database.

I followed this [Core Data tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZJpsszfTHM).

I code following content in Xcode:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initCoredataFunctionalities()
}

func initCoredataFunctionalities() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let viewContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:"category",into:viewContext) //this line shows the error of Unresolved symbol in NSEntityDescription
}
```

Can you guys give me an solutions? Help will be appreciated.

**Xcode version: 8.3.3**

**Swift version: 3.1**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the signature that you need for Swift 3.1

Have you added `import CoreData` at the top of your file? It doesn't come for free in `UIKit`

Comment: Awesome. I didn't noticed that. Thank you

Comment: one more thing. . Xcode is not smart enough when compare to Android Studio. Can you give your suggestion?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "smart enough" . The only alternative to Xcode is AppCode by jetbrains but it does cost $$ per year and IMO is ugly as sin.

Comment: i means, android studio will predict which package to import when we click Ctrl+space. it will show list of packages can import to that particular class.